# What's this symbol {0} name and what does it mean?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've found this symbol `{0}`, what's this symbol mean?

Comment: show some code of how it was used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most often used as part of a string formatting function, and means that the first argument in a (zero-based) list should replace it. For example:

```
var output = String.Format("{0},{1}", "Hello", "World") // Gives "Hello, World"
```

String formatting is a common element in data binding, so you will also often see it as part of binding expressions.

Comment: When posting code, please indent by four spaces (or highlight and use the `{}` button) to get code syntax highlighting to work.

Answer (score 1):

Its a string substitution markers.

Take a look at this example, it explains the use of these Symbols:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    string value1 = "Dot";
    string value2 = "Net";
    string value3 = "Perls";

    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}", // <-- This is called a format string.
        value1,                        // <-- These are substitutions.
        value2,
        value3);
    }
}
```

This causes the output:

> Dot, Net, Perls

Answer (score 0):

It can be used for [string formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx):

```
DateTime dat = new DateTime(2012, 1, 17, 9, 30, 0); 
string city = "Chicago";
int temp = -16;
string output = String.Format("At {0} in {1}, the temperature was {2} degrees.",
                              dat, city, temp);
Console.WriteLine(output);
// The example displays the following output: 
//    At 1/17/2012 9:30:00 AM in Chicago, the temperature was -16 degrees.
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a placeholder (example):

```
int selectedItem = 1;

// Generate the output string
string output = string.Format("You selected item {0} from the list.", selectedItem);

Console.WriteLine(output);     // Outputs "You selected item 5 from the list."
```

Answer (score 0):

It is  a zero-based indexed placeholders, called format items, in a composite format string.

At run time, each format item is replaced with the string representation of the corresponding argument in a parameter list. If the value of the argument is null, it is replaced with `String.Empty`.

For example, the following call to the Format(String, Object, Object, Object) method includes a format string with three format items, {0}, {1}, and {2}, and an argument list with three items.

Detailed formatting help can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx